# LoadLibrary vs build configuration

Tags: c++, windows, dll, loadlibrary

I use LoadLibrary to dynamically load a library in my application. In Visual Studio, I can set different build configurations: x86 or x64 / Debug or Release. I can also build a library from source in different configurations but how to implement loading library in my application which chooses appropriate target based on build configuration which is set in Visual Studio, for example: when I build x64-Release application LoadLibrary should also load x64-Release library.

Comment: Give the DLLs different names eg `my_dll_x64_debug.dll`, `my_dll_x64_release.dll` etc.  Or if you have many DLLs for each ABI use folders named for the ABI and put the corresponding set of DLLs in each folder.

Comment: But how at runtime choose an appropriate library ? It looks like I need some condition to set a path for LoadLibrary.

Comment: Use the [Predefined macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=msvc-170) to detect the built ABI.  eg `_WIN32` and `_WIN64` ...

Comment: @Irbis - The program has to know what you did at build time - to add a suffix to the library name and/or look in a specific directory. There are [macros defined for that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=msvc-170), like `_DEBUG` and `_WIN64`

Comment: Not a general solution but in some few scenarios it can be applicable to simply place the right dll into the same directory as the executable – all dlls then with equal names or you look up the dll by the common prefix only.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setdlldirectoryw